# Problem with switches and flutter interface

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeI3O.jpg)

I would like when the manual function is activated, the auto function is deactivated, and vice versa, without interfering with when I hold the auto or manual function, it opens another configuration tab related to a certain function

This is the code for the home page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/model/device_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/pages/home/widgets/devices.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/utils/string_to_color.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<DeviceModel> devices = [
    DeviceModel(
      name: 'Auto.',
      isActive: true,
      color: "#ff5f5f",
      icon: 'lib/assets/svg/light.svg',
    ),
    DeviceModel(
      name: 'Manual',
      isActive: false,
      color: "#7739ff",
      icon: 'lib/assets/svg/ac.svg',
    ),
    DeviceModel(
      name: 'Luz',
      isActive: false,
      color: "#c9c306",
      icon: 'lib/assets/svg/tv.svg',
    ),
    DeviceModel(
      name: 'Smart Sound',
      isActive: false,
      color: "#c207db",
      icon: 'lib/assets/svg/speaker.svg',
    ),
  ];

  bool isActiveAuto = true;
  bool isActiveManual = false;

  void onChangedAuto(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isActiveAuto = value;
      isActiveManual = !value;
    });
  }

  void onChangedManual(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isActiveManual = value;
      isActiveAuto = !value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: <Color>[Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 236, 252), Colors.white],
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 0),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      "Painel Controller",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 28,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      minRadius: 32,
                      backgroundImage:
                          AssetImage("lib/assets/images/user.webp"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: const [
                                  Text(
                                    "Um total de 4 Serviços",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "Control Sun lounger",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      height: 1.1,
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.more_horiz,
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: GridView.builder(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20),
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                                childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                              ),
                              itemCount: devices.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                                return Devices(
                                  name: devices[index].name,
                                  svg: devices[index].icon,
                                  color: devices[index].color.toColor(),
                                  isActiveState: devices[index].isActive,
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      devices[index].isActive = val;
                                      if (devices[index].name == 'Manual') {
                                        devices
                                            .firstWhere(
                                                (d) => d.name == 'Auto.')
                                            .isActive = !val;
                                        isActiveManual = val;
                                        isActiveAuto = !val;
                                      } else if (devices[index].name ==
                                          'Auto.') {
                                        devices
                                            .firstWhere(
                                                (d) => d.name == 'Manual')
                                            .isActive = !val;
                                        isActiveAuto = val;
                                        isActiveManual = !val;
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  onChangedAuto: onChangedAuto,
                                  onChangedManual: onChangedManual,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code devices:

```
import 'package:animations/animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/pages/compass/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/pages/control/UniversalControllerApp.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Devices extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final String svg;
  final Color color;
  final bool isActiveState;
  final Function(bool) onChanged;
  final Function(bool) onChangedAuto;
  final Function(bool) onChangedManual;

  const Devices({
    Key? key,
    required this.name,
    required this.svg,
    required this.color,
    required this.isActiveState,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.onChangedAuto,
    required this.onChangedManual,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DevicesState createState() => _DevicesState();
}

class _DevicesState extends State<Devices> {
  bool isActive = false;
  bool _isActiveAuto = false;
  bool _isActiveManual = false;

  Timer? longPressTimer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isActive = widget.isActiveState;
    _isActiveAuto = widget.isActiveState;
    _isActiveManual = !widget.isActiveState;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    longPressTimer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void handleLongPressStart() {
    if (widget.name == "Auto.") {
      longPressTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomeCompassPage(),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  void handleLongPressEnd() {
    if (widget.name == "Auto.") {
      longPressTimer?.cancel();
    }
  }

  void openPage() {
    if (widget.name == "Auto.") {
      widget.onChangedManual(false);
      widget.onChangedAuto(_isActiveAuto);
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeCompassPage(),
        ),
      );
    } else if (widget.name == "Manual") {
      widget.onChangedAuto(false);
      widget.onChangedManual(_isActiveManual);
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPressStart: (_) => handleLongPressStart(),
      onLongPressEnd: (_) => handleLongPressEnd(),
      child: OpenContainer(
        transitionType: ContainerTransitionType.fadeThrough,
        transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        closedElevation: 0,
        openElevation: 0,
        openShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
        closedShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
        openBuilder: (BuildContext context, VoidCallback _) {
          if (widget.name == "Auto.") {
            return HomeCompassPage();
          } else {
            return MyHomePage();
          }
        },
        tappable: true,
        closedBuilder: (BuildContext _, VoidCallback openContainer) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onLongPressStart: (_) => handleLongPressStart(),
            onLongPressEnd: (_) => handleLongPressEnd(),
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey[300]!,
                  width: 0.6,
                ),
                color: isActive ? widget.color : Colors.white,
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isActive = !isActive;
                    if (widget.name == "Auto.") {
                      _isActiveManual = false;
                      _isActiveAuto = isActive;
                    } else if (widget.name == "Manual") {
                      _isActiveAuto = false;
                      _isActiveManual = isActive;
                    }
                  });
                  widget.onChanged(isActive);
                  if (widget.name == "Auto.") {
                    _isActiveManual = false;
                    _isActiveAuto = isActive;
                  } else if (widget.name == "Manual") {
                    _isActiveAuto = false;
                    _isActiveManual = isActive;
                  }
                },
                onLongPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isActive = !isActive;
                  });
                  widget.onChanged(isActive);
                  if (widget.name == "Manual") {
                    openContainer(); // Abrir a página específica para "Manual"
                  } else if (widget.name == "Auto.") {
                    openContainer(); // Abrir a página específica para "Auto."
                  }
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            widget.svg,
                            color: isActive ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 14,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 65,
                            child: Text(
                              widget.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                height: 1.2,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: isActive ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Transform.scale(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        scaleY: 0.8,
                        scaleX: 0.85,
                        child: CupertinoSwitch(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              isActive = !isActive;
                              if (widget.name == "Auto.") {
                                _isActiveManual = false;
                                _isActiveAuto = true;
                                widget.onChangedAuto(value);
                              } else if (widget.name == "Manual") {
                                _isActiveAuto = false;
                                _isActiveManual = true;
                                widget.onChangedManual(value);
                              }
                            });
                            widget.onChanged(value);
                          },
                          value: isActive,
                          activeColor: isActive
                              ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4)
                              : Colors.black,
                          trackColor: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The expected:
Seen in the image, what was expected was that when you click on the manual or auto functions, they are activated, and when you click on a function, the other is automatically deactivated, and when you hold the functions, it goes to another page, which are the configuration pages of the functions

The result:
The result was that, everything worked as expected, apart from when clicking on one of the functions, deactivating the other function.